# Roger Strong clearly knows Frank is lying at dinner, but in the very next scene seems oblivious. Why?

Tags: plot-explanation, catch-me-if-you-can

During the dinner at the Strongs' house in *Catch Me If You Can* Roger Strong clearly knows Frank is lying, but in the very next scene seems oblivious. Are we supposed to believe that he bought the lie about the professor's dog being dead or that he just doesn't care?